# error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Rectangle' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++

I'm required to write a function to overload the ==operator to compare width, height and colour. I need to return 'Y' if its equal and 'N' if its not.

This is my code which I think is correct, but keeps giving me the error:

> error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Rectangle' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I've searched for an answer and nothing came close to comparing 3 data as most examples are for comparing 2 datas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
private:
    float width;
    float height;
    char colour;
public:
    Rectangle()
    {
        width=2;
        height=1;
        colour='Y';
    }
    ~Rectangle(){}
    float getWidth() { return width; }
    float getHeight() { return height; }
    char getColour() { return colour; }

    Rectangle(float newWidth, float newHeight, char newColour)
    {
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
        colour = newColour;
    }

    char operator== (const Rectangle& p1){

        if ((width==p1.width) && (height==p1.height) && (colour==p1.colour))
            return 'Y';
        else
            return 'N';
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Rectangle rectA;
    Rectangle rectB(1,2,'R');
    Rectangle rectC(3,4,'B');
    cout << "width and height of rectangle A is := " << rectA.getWidth() << ", " << rectA.getHeight() << endl;
    cout << "Are B and C equal? Ans: " << rectB==rectC << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I realize that your assignment is to have `operator==()` return 'Y' or 'N'. but you should mention to your instructor that that's a terrible, awful, really, really bad requirement to have in an assignment.  It may give students the idea that having `operator==()` work like that is OK in real life.  Then when they try something like "if (rectB == rectC) { /* shouldn't get here */ }" they get a nice little surprise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"<<" is higher precedence than "==".  Put your comparison in parentheses:

```
cout << "Are B and C equal? Ans: " << (rectB == rectC) << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need some parentheses:

```
cout << "Are B and C equal? Ans: " << (rectB==rectC) << endl;
```

It's an operator precedence issue; the `<<` is being applied to `rectB` before the `==` runs.

Comment: Sometimes I hate the random sorting.

Comment: thanks. think i've just made myself stupider with this stupid qns.

Comment: No, I'd say most people who work with C++ have done this at one time or another. What you can learn from this is that even when errors seem cryptic, they often have all the information you need. You could have looked at the message and wondered, "Why does the compiler think I'm trying to use an operator << with a Rectangle?" And that would have led you to the correct answer.

Comment: the codes cout << "Are B and C equal? Ans: " << rectB==rectC << endl;
are actually part and given in the qns, so im not really sure if adding the brackets are right. but since its working, i'm going to ask my lecturer abt it.

Comment: Funny how this answer is pretty much identical to mine, and was posted 2 seconds earlier, and yet didn't get voted up as much as mine.  And yeah, why the down votes??

Comment: @RealiX - so your instructor not only gives you an assignment to code up a broken `operator==()` but also gives you broken test/example use code?  Yikes...